# How can I search for sub-groups of dataframe that contains specific pairs of data?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, python-itertools

I have a dataset which contains orders, and items in those orders. What I want to find is which item pairs exist together in which group. For example, I want to find orders which has 6395477 and 6391546 together, in this case order 20220627-0015 and 20220627-0014 have them.

```
ORDER_ID     ITEM_ID
20220627-0015            6395477
20220627-0015            6391546
20220627-0015            6385826
20220627-0015            6385822
20220627-0015            6385810
20220627-0015            6385797
20220627-0015            6379808
20220627-0014            6395477
20220627-0014            6391546
20220627-0014            6386347
20220627-0014            6385814
20220627-0014            6385812
20220627-0014            6385810
20220627-0014            6384898
20220627-0013            6395592
20220627-0013            6395583
20220627-0013            6394927
20220627-0013            6386403
20220627-0013            6384293
20220627-0013            6380162
20220627-0013            6379830
20220627-0013            6379828
```

I created the item pairs from the `items` list using the code:

```
x= [tuple(x) for i,x in items.iteritems() for x in combinations(x,2) ]
```

and then I found the `orders` that contains 1900th elements of the `x` together with the code:

```
orders=df.loc[df['Item_Id'].isin(x[1900])].groupby('Order_Id', as_index=False).nunique()

order_list=orders.loc[orders['Item_Id'] == len(x[1901]), 'Order_Id'].to_list()
```

and I get the result as I wanted to:

```
[91158728,91158755,91158756,'20220627-0015']
```

I created a function to easily loop over the item pairs and tested it:

```
def ordfunc(df1,ls1,i):
    orders = df1.loc[df1['Item_Id'].isin(ls1[i])].groupby('Order_Id', as_index=False).nunique()
    order_list=orders.loc[orders['Item_Id'] == len(ls1[i]), 'Order_Id'].to_list()
    return order_list
```

I tried to get the result with the loop below but kernel couldn't handle it

```
final_list = [list(ordfunc(df,x,i)) for i in range(len(x)) ]
```

How can I create the loop that iterates over roughly 1.7 m item pairs and gives the list of list that contains those pairs together?

Comment: Now is match tuple `(6395477,6391546)` because in groups are values together like `6395477,6391546,6385826`. If in some groups are values like `6395477,100,6391546,6385826` it is pair or not?

Comment: @jezrael I updated the question. Like everyone said in comments , kernel couldn't handle it and I couldn't get any results.  Do you have any idea how to correct the loop and iterate over 1.7m item pairs more efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

Solution for not test consecutive orders:

```
v = (6395477, 6391546)
df1 = df[df['ITEM_ID'].isin(v)]
print (df1)
        ORDER_ID  ITEM_ID
0  20220627-0015  6395477
1  20220627-0015  6391546
7  20220627-0014  6395477
8  20220627-0014  6391546

orders = df1.loc[df1['ORDER_ID'].duplicated(keep=False), 'ORDER_ID'].unique().tolist()
print (orders)
['20220627-0015', '20220627-0014']
```

If need all pairs to separately DataFrame:

```
from  itertools import combinations

L = [(i, tuple(y)) for i, x in df.groupby('ORDER_ID')['ITEM_ID'] for y in combinations(x, 2)]

df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['a','b'])
print (df)
                a                   b
0   20220627-0013  (6395592, 6395583)
1   20220627-0013  (6395592, 6394927)
2   20220627-0013  (6395592, 6386403)
3   20220627-0013  (6395592, 6384293)
4   20220627-0013  (6395592, 6380162)
..            ...                 ...
65  20220627-0015  (6385822, 6385797)
66  20220627-0015  (6385822, 6379808)
67  20220627-0015  (6385810, 6385797)
68  20220627-0015  (6385810, 6379808)
69  20220627-0015  (6385797, 6379808)

[70 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @Tolunay - Super, is some reason for all pairs?

Comment: I am going to analyze the effect of those combinations to the order quality. For example what is the likelihood of low order quality when those two items are in the same order together.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is only one same item per order, you can use:

```
pair = (6395477, 6391546)
orders = df[df['ITEM_ID'].isin(pair)].value_counts('ORDER_ID').loc[lambda x: x == 2].index
print(orders)

# Output
Index(['20220627-0014', '20220627-0015'], dtype='object', name='ORDER_ID')
```

You can also use `df.where`:

```
orders = (df.where(df['ITEM_ID'].isin(pair)).groupby('ORDER_ID')['ITEM_ID']
            .nunique().loc[lambda x: x == 2].index)
```

Comment: hmmm, `df[df['ITEM_ID'].isin(pair)]` not test pair, becasue there should be some value between them.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: `6395477,100,6391546` is wrongly selected like pair

Comment: Why it's wrong? I just mark ORDER_ID that contain the pair whatever the order

Comment: hmmm,, then I understand consecutive pairs.

Comment: The OP said *together* but was not specified consecutive. However in this example, the `item_id` are consecutive.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I forgot to mention that I need to create list of every possible pair. For example there are 1871 different items and I want to look for every possible pair in each order. pairs = (6395477, 6391546);(6395477,6394927);(6395477,6384293). Do you have any idea how to create those pairs ?

Comment: @Tolunay - check another answer.

Comment: @Tolunay. Do you want to check consecutive pairs or all pairs?

Comment: No, not consecutive. I want to check every possible pair C(1871,2) = 1749385 pairs in total

Comment: Do you know it could take very long time if you do not use multiprocessing?

Comment: I can imagine that but the task is to find every couple that exists in the same order. After that I am going to analyze the effect of those combinations to the order quality

Answer (score 0):

To do this, I created a list of the items you want to check for:

```
ITEM_IDS = [6395477, 6391546]
```

Then I filtered the dataframe using [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) to filter on the rows that contain one of those 2 products:

```
df.loc[df['ITEM_ID'].isin(ITEM_IDS)]

        ORDER_ID  ITEM_ID
0  20220627-0015  6395477
1  20220627-0015  6391546
7  20220627-0014  6395477
8  20220627-0014  6391546
```

You can then group this up on `ORDER_ID`, and use [`nunique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) to give the count of the number of unique `ITEM_IDs`:

```
orders = df.loc[df['ITEM_ID'].isin(ITEM_IDS)].groupby('ORDER_ID', as_index=False).nunique()

        ORDER_ID  ITEM_ID
0  20220627-0014        2
1  20220627-0015        2
```

Then the `ORDER_IDs` that contain all of the checked items are the rows where `ITEM_ID == len(ITEM_IDS)`, which can be done as below, to return a list of `ORDER_IDs`:

```
orders.loc[orders['ITEM_ID'] == len(ITEM_IDS), 'ORDER_ID'].to_list()

['20220627-0014', '20220627-0015']
```