# Pandas: Generate Experimenter-Subject Combinations Per Day

Tags: pandas, comparison, pairwise

I have a set of experiment days and subjects (anonymised subset below) in a dataframe. How do I generate all the pairwise comparisons per day in a new dataframe where subjects alse play the role of experimenter?

**Input:**

| Day | Subject |
| --- | --- |
| Monday | Alpha |
| Monday | Bravo |
| Monday | Charlie |
| Wednesday | Delta |
| Wednesday | Echo |
| Wednesday | Foxtrot |
| Wednesday | Golf |
| Wednesday | Hotel |

**Expected Output:**

| Day | Subject | Experimenter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Monday | Alpha | Bravo |
| Monday | Alpha | Charlie |
| Monday | Bravo | Charlie |
| Wednesday | Delta | Echo |
| Wednesday | Delta | Foxtrot |
| Wednesday | Delta | Golf |
| Wednesday | Delta | Hotel |
| Wednesday | Echo | Foxtrot |
| Wednesday | Echo | Golf |
| Wednesday | Echo | Hotel |
| Wednesday | Foxtrot | Golf |
| Wednesday | Foxtrot | Hotel |
| Wednesday | Golf | Hotel |

So far, I an only able to generate the total set of combinations but not by day!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import itertools as it

df = pd.DataFrame({'Day': ['Monday', 'Monday', 'Monday', 'Wednesday', 'Wednesday', 'Wednesday', 'Wednesday', 'Wednesday'],
                    'Subject': ['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie', 'Delta', 'Echo', 'Foxtrot', 'Golf', 'Hotel']})

pair_order_list = it.combinations(df['Subject'], 2)
pairs = list(pair_order_list)
```

**Actual Output**

> [('Alpha', 'Bravo'), ('Alpha', 'Charlie'), ('Alpha', 'Delta'),...]

Any advice would be welcome?

Answer (score 0):

The following code appears to generate the expected output:

```
from  itertools import combinations

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72811105/how-can-i-search-for-sub-groups-of-dataframe-that-contains-specific-pairs-of-dat.
L = [(i, tuple(y)) for i, x in df.groupby('Day')['Subject'] for y in combinations(x, 2)]
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['Day','SubjExp'])

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550414/how-can-i-split-a-column-of-tuples-in-a-pandas-dataframe.
df_2[['Subject', 'Experimenter']] = pd.DataFrame(df_2['SubjExp'].tolist(), index=df_2.index)
df_2 = df_2.drop('SubjExp', axis=1)
```